# Proof of "invariance of domain theorem"

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

How can I get a proof of "invariance of domain theorem"? Of course, I would like to know brief explanation. Now, this statement is here ; http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain . Thank you for your help!

Comment: Here's one. http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/brouwers-fixed-point-and-invariance-of-domain-theorems-and-hilberts-fifth-problem/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there some elementary proof of invariance of domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475933/is-there-some-elementary-proof-of-invariance-of-domain)