# Why should this manifold be an open set?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

**Problem:**

Suppose that $\Sigma \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $d$. Is it true that $\Sigma$ is open? How can I prove it?

I tried using directly the definition of manifold but nothing has come.

I define $\Sigma \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ to be a smooth manifold if every point has an open neighborhood $U$ which is diffeomorphic to an open set of $\mathbb{R}^k$ where in this case $k=d$.

Comment: To be clear, you are assuming $\Sigma$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: Seems like this needs invariance of domain.

Comment: This would probably be easiest to answer if you told us your precise definition of manifold.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes I am

Comment: @Randall I do not know such an argument, could you try to think to a basic way to solve it?

Comment: What you are asking is equivalent to the [invariance of domain theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain). The best proofs nowadays use some algebraic topology. Perhaps you can look up Brouwer's original proof, which I believe was written before the abstractions and simplifications of singular homology theory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there some elementary proof of invariance of domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475933/is-there-some-elementary-proof-of-invariance-of-domain)

Comment: That link also directs you to [this relevant link on Terry Tao's site](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/brouwers-fixed-point-and-invariance-of-domain-theorems-and-hilberts-fifth-problem/).

Comment: @LeeMosher This only needs smooth invariance of domain, which is elementary. To the OP: Think Inverse Function Theorem.

Comment: Ah, good point.

Comment: If one wanted to make it even simpler, since $\Sigma$ is an embedded smooth manifold, one only needs to show that every diffeomorphism is an open map, but the Inverse Function Theorem is a good hammer as @Thorgott notices.